How to stop MP3 files from opening in Link to Windows app?
I have a Samsung M33 5G, One UI 6.1. Any audio file I try to open in my files, opens in the Link to Windows app, with the option of file share to other device.
The only way to open the audio is by disabling the Link to Windows app.
Here is the Video
Does anyone know how to solve this without disabling Link to Windows?

You need to remove the asdociation to the app.

Open Settings
Select Apps
Find and select the Windows Apps
Select Set as Default
untick or unselect Open supported links


No it doesn't work still , i screen recorded it for you . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S47-jM_lyvS1Sh3M_SkLZdRMy5gW8eia/view?usp=drivesdk

AFAIK, default app preferences can be reset from "Reset app preferences", not "Open supported links". This will reset all default app preferences though (but not the predefined "Default apps"). // cc @SuTech

@AndrewT. Here you go https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t725crgljxNw2gyKUWEjFvTEPWGYzrgu/view?usp=drivesdk , still doesn't work
